# very strange: if x not in statement Python 2.7

Tags: if-statement, python-2.7

I encountered a very strange thing, to me at least.

```
if month not in (02, 04, 06, 11):
        print "Good"
```

whenever I add `09` to the tuple i got the error called: `SyntaxError: invalid token` and it's only for this particular number.

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a leading `0` on a number, Python interprets that as [a base-8 (octal) number](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-octinteger). Remove the leading `0`:

```
>>> 10
10
>>> 010
8
>>> 9
9
>>> 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    09
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Python 3 has improved on this; *all* numbers with a leading `0` are considered invalid now, to create a octal number you *always* have to use the `0o` prefix instead:

```
>>> 010
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    010
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o10
8
```

Comment: In fact - I think I've seen this two or three times recently - might add it to our FAQ list ;)

Comment: I can imagine; it's an easy thing to trigger and then misunderstand.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with leading `0`s are considered octal, so `09` is invalid... Just drop the 0's

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to get rid of the zeros before the numbers it might be interpreting it as an octal number...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.(reason is already answered why 09 provide error)

```
month='05'
if month not in ('02', '04', '06', '11','09'):
        print "Good"
```